# How to select a product id AND also select all other products with the same order number?

Tags: mysql, select

I have a order table looking like this.

```
produkt_id ordernumber

2075        12345
3456        12345
1123        12345
1212        54321
1166        54321
```

Now I want to select all products based on where produkt_id = 2075 and also select all other products from the same order based on the order number that we get from the first select - produkt_id = 2075

I have tried different variants of this and others.

```
select * from ordrar o where o.produkt_id=2075 and  o.ordernummer in (select p.ordernummer from ordrar p where p.ordernummer=o.ordernummer);
```

Any input appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need all the ordernumber sthat has the ordernumber of produkt_id(2075) You can take the ordernumber of 2075 and get all the data which has the same ordernumber.

```
select * from ordrar  where ordernummer = (select ordernummer from ordrar  where produkt_id = 2075);
```

Result will be :

```
produkt_id ordernumber

2075        12345
3456        12345
1123        12345
```